# MySQL merging current database with backup SQL file

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysql

I have a database 'books' with 100,000ish items in it.

All the items that contained "Dostoevsky" as the author were deleted. But, I have a backup SQL file that my cronjob made.

I would like to put those 20,000 items by Dostoyevsky into the database from the SQL file.

Note: The database has changed drastically since the backup cronjob ran. So, I must find a way to not delete anything from the current database and add all items with that characteristic from the old DB (not just boot up the old DB).

I don't know what the first step would be. mysqldump doesn't seem to have this capability, and I am having a little trouble "importing" the SQL file without overwriting the current DB.

**EDIT 1**

I did a `sudo grep "books" backup.sql`

and it returned:

```
INSERT INTO `db` VALUES ('localhost','books','selector','Y','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N');
-- Current Database: `books`
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `books` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `books`;
```

Should I replace all the lines with books to old_books?

**EDIT 2**

`sed -i -- 's/books/old_books/g' *backup.sql*` worked for making the sql file not overwrite the current DB

Answer (score 2):

Restore the backup into a new schema, so you'll have `books` and `old_books`. Depending on how you created your backup, if it has `use books` in it or not, you'll need to rewrite or you can just import it.

Once you have two schemas next to each other write a select against the old schema that selects all the rows you would like to re-import into the new one. You'll have to make the query so it matches the new schema perfectly. Along the lines of this

```
select title, author, 'invented value only found in new schema' from old_books.books where auther like '%dostojevski%';
```

Then when that query gives you exactly what you want change it into a `insert into ... select`, like this

```
insert into books.books
select title, author, 'invented value only found in new schema' from old_books.books where auther like '%dostojevski%';
```

And that should be it. Take new backup before so if it fails you can go back.

Comment: Thanks, I am a little hung up on the 1st step of you answer. Can you see Edit 1 in my question?

Comment: sed seems perfect. I don't know if all occurances of the word 'book' can be replaced. You can check that by taking a diff between backup.sql before and after you run sed.